# How do i tile li tags regardless of their height?

Tags: html, css

I am using `u`l `li` tags, and some `li`'s have a lot of text therefore the height of that `li` gets larger. The display is set to `inline-block` so any horizontal overflow of `li`'s it shoves them in a new row. But the new row aligns to the bottom of the tall `li` that was in the previous row. Im trying to get it to look like the picture I have attached.

```
<div class="indexBodyGraduates">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="Pictures/graduate2.jpg" width="150px" height="200px" />

                <p class="graduateText"></p>
                <p class="graduateName"></p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="Pictures/graduate3.jpg" width="150px" height="200px" />
                <p class="graduateText"></p>
                <p class="graduateName"></p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="Pictures/graduate2.jpg" width="150px" height="200px" />
                <p class="graduateText"></p>
                <p class="graduateName"></p>
            </li>
        </ul>


    </div>


    <style>

    .indexBodyGraduates {
        position:absolute;
        top:1010px;
        height:auto;
        padding-top:30px;
        padding-bottom:30px;
        width:1390px;
        left:0px;
        background-color:#ccc;
    }

    .indexBodyGraduates ul {

    }
    .indexBodyGraduates li {
        list-style-type:none;
        display:inline-block;
        text-align:center;
        background-color: #5b5b5d;
        padding: 20px;
        color:white;
        border-radius:20px;
        margin-right:30px;
        margin-bottom:30px;

    }

    .graduateText {
        width:250px;
        text-align:left;
        padding-top:10px;
    }

    .graduateName {
        position:relative;
        font-size:13px;
        bottom:20px;
        text-align:right;
        padding-right:20px;
    }
    </style>
```

My goal is to tile them like this. So they just float to the tile above.

[image: picture]

Comment: This is commonly referred to as a "Masonry" layout (which is also the name of a jQuery Plugin to achieve this style).

Comment: Thank you for the response! Im not too good with jQuery so I'm staying away from that. I figured out a pure CSS way of doing it. I sized them so 4 Columns fit horizontal. Then put each column as separate ul tags. I set the ul tags 'display: inline;'. Then the li tags in each ul i set them to display:block;. Works Perfectly!